# Can values or parameters be passed into user control?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I haven't used these in awhile. I was just wondering is it possible to pass values or parameters to a user control from the aspx page. Say you register a control and then use it using something like

```
<uc1:SampleUserControl id="SampleUserControl1" runat="server"></uc1:SampleUserControl>
```

style syntax. Can you pass parameters in there?

Comment: I found that it was necessary to set the CodeBehind property in the .ascx file to the associated ascx.cs/ascx.vb file

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes:

```
<my:Control runat="server" MyPublicProperty="Value1" MyPublicProperty2="Value2"/>
```

Any public property can be set in the markup as indicated above. You can get more advanced than this and support child elements, etc. too. [See more information](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/user-controls/using/).

Comment: Another approach is add `Control.MyPublicProperty = "Value1";` inside the Page_Load on the `.cs` file.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL Yes, but in general it is preferred to do what you can in the markup. If you have to do something complex, then it goes in the code-behind. If you can do it in the markup easily, then do it there. Even better - switch to MVC and stop using server controls! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Create public properties in the code behind of the user control and then these could be used as attributes while declaring the user control in the page. Check [here](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article16.aspx)