# ASP.Net Webform UserControl set label Text

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a UserControl in asp.Net. I want to set the properties like in this Question
[Can values or parameters be passed into user control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254214/can-values-or-parameters-be-passed-into-user-control)

I place the control like this into my site

```
    <uc1:BootstrapTextRow runat="server" id="BootstrapTextRow" Text="" LabelText="Season"/>
```

This is the UserControl ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="BootstrapTextRow.ascx.cs" Inherits="RANDOMAPP.UserControls.TextRow" %>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <asp:Label ID="lblLabel" runat="server" Text='<%= this.LabelText %>' CssClass="control-label" AssociatedControlID="tbTextbox"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbTextbox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-sm" Text='<%= this.Text %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here my CS file

```
public partial class TextRow : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private String m_LabelText;

    public String LabelText
    {
        get { return m_LabelText; }
        set { m_LabelText = value; }
    }

    private String m_Text;

    public String Text
    {
        get { return m_Text; }
        set { m_Text = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

but my site looks like this

[image]

How can I achieve that the proper Text is displayed ?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `Text='<%= ... %>'` from the markup:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblLabel" runat="server" CssClass="control-label" AssociatedControlID="tbTextbox" />
<asp:TextBox ID="tbTextbox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-sm" />
```

And define your properties like this:

```
public String LabelText
{
    get { return lblLabel.Text; }
    set { lblLabel.Text = value; }
}

public String Text
{
    get { return tbTextBox.Text; }
    set { tbTextBox.Text = value; }
}
```

Comment: I want to use the Text on some other places in the user control too. I don't want to change the sourcecode every time I change something on the markup

Comment: You can use the `LabelText` property in other parts of your code if you want, even in markup.

Comment: that was my initial question, because it only prints <%= LabelText %>

Comment: Inside the user control itself, it would be easier to use the property in code-behind (the binding expression in markup could be trickier than I said in my previous comment). In the form where the user control is included however, you could use expressions like: `<%= BootstrapTextRow.LabelText %>` in other controls of the form.